# Linq subquery - getting InvalidOperationException as soon as I'm trying to iterate through the results set

Tags: c#, linq

The code will compile and even run, but as soon as I'm doing anything with the result, I will get InvalidOperationException or NotSupportedException

```
  var movies = from m in data.Movies
                         where m.Rating > -1 && m.GenresLinks.Contains
                         (
                         (from g in data.GenresLinks 
                          where g.GenreID == queryGenre select g).FirstOrDefault()
                         )
                         orderby m.InsertedIn descending
                         select m;


                return movies.ToArray();//Exception here
```

Comment: What sort of LINQ is this? LINQ to SQL, LINQ to Objects?

Comment: LINQ-To-SQL queries don't execute until you try to use them, or when you call one of the "To" methods for the result.  You need to give the ACTUAL Exception text that you are getting.

Comment: Please let us know the complete exception details of the exception you get. You can get only one, either `InvalidOperationException` **or** `NotSupportedException`. Both at the same time is not possible. More: Are you using LINQ2SQL? Entity Framework? LINQ to Objects?

Comment: Yes it is LINQ to SQL. Here is the exception text: An exception occured during the execution of '
Extent<MoviesWebApp.Movies>.Where(m => ((Convert(m.Rating) > -1) AndAlso m.GenresLinks.Contains(value(ASP.default_aspx).data.GenresLinks.Where(g => (g.GenreID == Default.queryGenre)).FirstOrDefault()))).OrderByDescending(m => m.InsertedIn)'. See InnerException for more details.

Comment: Inner exception message: "Argument expression is not valid"

Comment: did you try to do this with a sql statement to make sure you are getting valid results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I am missing something here, but you are returning movies with a rating > -1 and a genre of queryGenre, why don't you just to this?

```
var movies = from m in data.Movies 
             where m.Rating > -1 && 
                   m.GenreLinks.Any(gr => gr.GenreID == queryGenre) 
             orderby m.InsteredIn desc 
             select m;
```

Really need more info to be of help here though

Comment: Thanks fr the suggestion Mirko, as you said, I wasn't clear. GenreLinks is a list for a table that that link between Movies and Genres tables. so that each movie can have several genres.  Hope I make any sense.

Answer (score 0):

From where the error is thrown, you can determine that its cause is evaluating the query with `ToArray()`.

LINQ to SQL supports nested queries, so my best guess is that you are doing a `Contains(null)` and that it doesn't translate to SQL, so an error gets thrown when the `IQueryProvider` tries to evaluate the expression.